# Is there a Java compiler option to allow if(object)?

Tags: java, compiler-options

I want to be able to type something like this:

```
if (object) {
    // some code...
}
```

and have the compiler see it as this:

```
if (object != null) {
    // some code...
}
```

**Is there any way I can do this?**

Alternatively: is there anything that can be done in Eclipse or IntelliJ that will do this?

Comment: Alternatively: is there anything that can be done in Eclipse or IntelliJ that will do this?

Comment: That should be possible as a shortcut, like `sout`, `fori` and such.

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero Just curious as to why you would want to do something like this?

Comment: In Intellij you could create a live template, which is the IntelliJ name for `sout` like things.

Comment: @ChetanKinger I and others on my team complain that this is something we miss from C-based languages.

Comment: If you have to check for nulls that frequently that you found it worth investing the time to look for a workaround suggests you should also ask if you're not excessively using nullable returns (instead of e.g. throwing, null-object or simply letting the exception bubbling up). Especially since you mention a prior C-background, not every C-idiom that can be copied directly to java, fits too well into a mostly OO-world. In the long run you might benefit more from shedding the old habits.

Comment: @Durandal mostly, this is Android programming. When getting a GUI object, we must make sure it is not null before performing operations on it.

Comment: This is going to be so fun when the entire team uses it, and your IDEs silently replace `Boolean b; if (b) { }` with `Boolean b; if (b != null) { }` (Yes, won't exactly work with LiveTemplates, but still)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't any compiler settings you could set to get this behavior. I don't think you could really do this elegantly with a code generator (something like [Lombok](http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbJan2010.html)), either since you can't really annotate statements.

An alternative would be to use IntelliJ [Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/live-templates.html) for both `if (args != null)` and `if (args == null)`

- `ifn` expands to `if (args == null)`
- `inn` expands to `if (args != null)`

Comment: I believe you are missing the point. The OP is not looking for IDE shortcuts but a compiler option to allow if(object) where object is not a boolean

Comment: @ChetanKinger Although you're correct if only looking at the question, don't ignore my comments 

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero: Please don't leave important bits of the question in comments. They're harder to see.

Comment: @MichaelMyers I usually don't, but ever since including some meta information in a question and being told to leave that in a comment instead, I've been trying to find the line.

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero: I see. A good rule of thumb is that if you can't understand the question without the comment (as in this case, where it affects the answers), then the comment should be part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

When in IntelliJ press `ctrl + j`, then type: `inn` - and voilà:

```
if (args != null) {

}
```

Btw. this is called a [live template](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html)

Comment: I believe you are missing the point. The OP is not looking for IDE shortcuts but a compiler option to allow `if(object)` where object is not a `boolean`.

Comment: I didn't miss the point. This is an alternative as specified in the first comment by the author - "Alternatively: is there anything that can be done in Eclipse or IntelliJ that will do this? – "

Comment: My bad. I have edited the question and added the comment as part of the question to avoid the confusion.